# Stream работа с массивом

Tags: java-8, java-stream

помогите разобраться.

Есть вот такой кусочек кода со стримами. Есть некий массив found. Стримим его, фильтруем, чтобы объект не был Null, далее забираем параметр и кладем в лист.
Получаю массив этих элементов, все как надо, но мне нужно после каждого добавления элемента добавлять пробел " ", это нужно для запроса в Solr через In, он не работает без этих пробелов, так как Spring Data парсит неверно и в итоге склеивает значения в одну строку. Баг есть официальный.

То есть мне надо получить в итоге лист такого содержания:

["el1", " ", "el2", " ", .....], сейчас у меня ["el1", "el2"].

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это именно при помощи stream сделать?

```
List<String> s = found.stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getOrderNumber() != null)
                .map(e -> e.getOrderNumber())
                .distinct()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @Komdosh а как вообще было бы такое провернуть гарммотно со стримами? То есть как бы это сделать красиво, не стандартным перебором? Я это прошу не потому что чтобы за меня сделали, а чтобы наглядно понять, очень трудно мне даются эти лямбды и стримы.

Comment: ну в теории можно попробовать переписать коллектор кстати

Comment: прошу прощения за дезу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<String> s = found.stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getOrderNumber() != null)
                .map(e -> e.getOrderNumber())
                .distinct()
                .flatMap(i -> Stream.concat(Stream.of(i), Stream.of(" ")))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Спасибо, я ходил вокруг да около этого flatMap, но не понимал как его применить :) Правда он добавил вот как пробелы 19-082657,  , 17-145669,  , 17-005101, но да ладно. Я пробовал немного по другому, добавил еще один .map(и в массив s.add(" ")) сделал так.

Comment: ого, круто, как можно издеваться

Comment: Да, клевая штука эти стримы, но блин сложные, нужно много практики чтобы вникнуть. Я уже пол года с ними бьюсь, пока могу простые вещи сделать

Comment: @Владислав а вам точно нужен список, а не строка? Если строка, то лучше использовать `.collect(Collectors.joining(", "))`

Comment: @Владислав попробуйте прочитать "Лямбда-выражения в Java 8" Ричарда Уорбэртона, у него просто и доходчиво описана работа со стримами.

Comment: Да, так как в офф документации Spring Data есть описание "In findByNameIn(Collection<String> names)"

Comment: Сергей, спасибо большое. Обязательно прочту. А то это не дело не знать лямбды (

Comment: `.flatMap(x -> Stream.of(x, " "))`

Comment: @extrn и правда, что-то я наоверинжинирил :)